# How to undo accidental RAID initalization operation (recover data)?

Tags: raid, raid-1, data-recovery

**Summary of the problem:**
I have two disks re-configured as RAID 1. instead of copying the data to the empty disk, it deleted the data from the non-empty disk.

**Here's what happened:**
1. In the last few days, I reinstalled windows 8 twice.
2. I had 2 disks configured as RAID 1 and 1 SSD contained the OS.
3. While reinstalling windows 8 (1st time) on the SSD, I might have removed the RAID configurations from BIOS.
4. I made changes to the raid disk.
5. I reinstalled windows 8.
6. I noticed I see 3 disks (1 SSD, raid-disk1, raid-disk2)
7. Raid-disk1 was updated to my last changes (done after installing windows 8 for the 1st time)
8. Raid-disk2 was updated to BEFORE installing windows 8.
9. I formatted raid-disk2
10. I set SATA configuration to RAID in BIOS.
11. After restart, the disks was automatically configured as RAID and with status rebuild.
12. In windows 8 I get both disks as EMPTY!

**How do I restore the data?**

Thanks A LOT!
Omer

Answer (score 0):

Can u try with the below procedure and revert.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Regards,

Akhisar

Comment: It is always better to include the most important information into the reply. The link can stop functioning.